# Applying OpenMP to particular nested loops in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, nested, openmp

I've a problem in parallelizing a piece of code with openmp, I think that there is a conceptual problem with some operations that have to be made sequentially.

```
else if (PERF_ROWS <= MAX_ROWS && function_switch == true)
{
    int array_dist_perf[PERF_ROWS];
    int array_dist[MAX_ROWS];

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLUMNS;
                    i = i + 1 + (i % PERF_CLMN == 0 ? 1:0))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < PERF_ROWS; j++) //truncation perforation
        {
            array_dist_perf[j] = abs(input[j] - input_matrix[j][i]);
        }

        float av = mean(PERF_ROWS, array_dist_perf);

        float score = score_func(av);

        if (score > THRESHOLD_SCORE)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < MAX_ROWS; k++)
            {
                array_dist[k] = abs(input[k] - input_matrix[k][i]);
            }

            float av_real = mean(MAX_ROWS, array_dist);

            float score_real = score_func(av_real);

            rank_function(score_real, i);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is that "collapsed loops are not perfectly nested". I'm using Clion on g++-5. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, perfectly nested loops have the following form:

```
for (init1; cond1; inc1)
{
   for (init2; cond2; inc2)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Notice that the body of the outer loop consists solely of the inner loop and nothing else. This is definitely not the case with your code - you have plenty of other statements following the inner loop.

Second, your outer loop is not in the canonical form required by OpenMP. Canonical are loops for which the number of iterations and the iteration step can be easily pre-determined. Since what you are doing is skip an iteration each time `i` is a multiple of `PERF_CLMN`, you can rewrite the loop as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLUMNS; i++)
{
    if (i % PERF_CLMN == 1) continue;
    ...
}
```

This will create work imbalance depending on whether `MAX_COLUMNS` is a multiple of the number of threads or not. But there is yet another source or imbalance, namely the conditional evaluation of `rank_function()`. You should therefore utilise dynamic scheduling.

Now, apparently both `array_dist*` loops are meant to be private, which they are not in your case and that will result in data races. Either move the definition of the arrays within the loop body or use the `private()` clause.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) private(array_dist_perf,array_dist)
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLUMNS; i++)
{
    if (i % PERF_CLMN == 1) continue;
    ...
}
```

Now, for some unsolicited optimisation advice: the two inner loops are redundant as the first one is basically doing a subset of the work of the second one. You can optimise the computation and save on memory by using a single array only and let the second loop continue from where the first one ends. The final version of the code should look like:

```
else if (PERF_ROWS <= MAX_ROWS && function_switch == true)
{
    int array_dist[MAX_ROWS];

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) private(array_dist)
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        if (i % PERF_CLMN == 1) continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < PERF_ROWS; j++) //truncation perforation
        {
            array_dist[j] = abs(input[j] - input_matrix[j][i]);
        }

        float av = mean(PERF_ROWS, array_dist);

        float score = score_func(av);

        if (score > THRESHOLD_SCORE)
        {
            for (int k = PERF_ROWS; k < MAX_ROWS; k++)
            {
                array_dist[k] = abs(input[k] - input_matrix[k][i]);
            }

            float av_real = mean(MAX_ROWS, array_dist);

            float score_real = score_func(av_real);

            rank_function(score_real, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Another potential for optimisation lies in the fact that `input_matrix` is not accessed in a cache-friendly way. Transposing it will result in columns data being stored continuously in memory and improve the memory access locality.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, what do you mean cache friendly way? input_matrix is just a global variable because of huge dimension.

Comment: You are currently accessing it like `... input_matrix[k-1][i] input_matrix[k][i] input_matrix[k+1][i] ...`. Those elements are not consecutively stored in memory. If you would instead transpose the matrix and access it like `... input_matrix[i][k-1] input_matrix[i][k] input_matrix[i][k+1] ...`, the elements will be consecutively stored in memory and will be loaded as part of the same cache line, which will significantly speed-up the memory access.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately I have only six reputation and I cannot add the feedback, but you've solved my problem. =)